# Function that accepts an Int and returns a function

Tags: scala, functional-programming, user-defined-functions, scala-collections, higher-order-functions

Could someone explain, how do I write a function that takes an integer and returns another function using Scala Functional programming? To implement the following problem: A function taking a number as argument and returning a new function that also takes a number:

Additionally, when the new function is called it returns the sum of its argument and the original number.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the code explains itself:

```
def f(i: Int) = (n: Int) => n + i

// some tests
val f2 = f(2)

f2(10)  // yields 12
f2(20)  // yields 22
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The code it's self explanatory really.

Answer (score 2):

What I would add to Sebastian's answer is the concept behind it. Which would be the type of the function you are defining? What you are looking for is high-order functions, that is, functions that takes functions as arguments and also return functions.

So, what would be the type of the following function `f`?

```
def f(n: Int): ??? = (m: Int) => n + m
```

As you see from the lambda notation in Scala after `=`, it takes `m` which is an `Int` and returns the sum of `n` and `m`. You can express this idea in Scala using the following type `Int => Int`. Therefore, you can complete the types of your function likewise:

```
def f(n: Int): Int => Int = (m: Int) => n + m
```

On the REPL:

```
scala> def f(n: Int): Int => Int = (m: Int) => n + m
f: (n: Int)Int => Int
```

What if...

```
scala> :t f(1)
Int => Int
```

And...

```
scala> :t f(1)(2)
Int
```

So I can say things like:

```
scala> def addTwo = f(2)
```

Could you guess which will be the type of `addTwo`?

```
scala> :t addTwo
???
```

I'd suggest you to play around and get familiar with these constructions, they really make your code cleaner and smarter.